# RecyclerView Item doesn't change background color when tapping

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

After click on a item, the data connected with reyclerview has some changes, so I need `notifyDataSetChange()` as following:

```
rv.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position, MotionEvent e) {
                //modify data
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
}));
```

Without `notifyDataSetChanged()`, the background color item is changed when tapping. However, It doesn't work with `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Here is the item background:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

How can I change item background color as long as my finger hold on the screen with using `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside onClick item method?

---

Finally, I found the solution. Just make return value in onSingleTapUp to false, so the event will continue to fire to the root view of my item.

```
    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
//                return true;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are about to make it work.
The correct way to do it is to make a drawable like

> click_effect_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorLightGray" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Set it to your row item parent layout. Like if you have LinearLayout as parent of row item.
Then just use

```
android:background="@drawable/click_effect_background"
```

Also add blank click listener in ViewHolder class.

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
```

*You don't need to do all click stuff in code.*

Comment: The code snippet that you provided isn't much different from mine and it doesn't work.

Comment: Or you want to change background color with some condition?

Comment: I just want the item background changes color as long as my finger holds on the screen. After I lift the finger, the item background backs to its initial color.

Comment: set parent LinearLayout clickable:true property

Comment: Bro congrats, but i never used this method, It was always so easy for me to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the pressed state programatically after notifyDataSetChanged, then your view should show its state_pressed color background again:

[`view.setPressed(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPressed%28boolean%29)

Comment: I just want the background color changes as long as my finger still holds on the item layout.

Comment: You asked `How can I change item background color with notifyDataSetChanged() inside onClick item method?` and that is what it does :-) ...if you need more things to happen when your finger stops holding the item, then you should think about implementing an OnTouchListener.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below background. As the code will execute top to bottom at the time of rendering, if you press or focus on the view it will set corresponding color. If not then it will set normal color as mentioned at the last step.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
</selector>
```